# Vue.js how to set :id prefix string?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
class="tab-title" 
v-on:click="tab" 
v-for="(tabTitle,index) in tabTitleList"
:id="index"
```

I found this example in an vue community, but in my situation, I want my "id"  has a prefix, not just a number.

That is to say, if the index is 1, I want  `<span id='sp_1'></span>` instead of `<span id='1'></span>`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can just do, code should be self explanatory:

```
<div v-for="(tabTitle, index) in tabTitleList">
    <span :id="'sp_' + index"> {{tabTitle}} </span>
</div>
```

Documentation [link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind).

Answer (score 4):

If you have a unique id, do, you can just do like this:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in ritems" :id="['Row_' + item.id]">
        {{something}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

if you don't have a unique id, do this

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(item , index) in ritems" :id="['Row_' + index]">
        {{something}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

in both, the result will be like this:

```
<ul>
    <li id="Row_12">
        something
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to dynamic the html attribut like :id,:class etc. with suffix & prefix string.

> **Prefix**

**Use concatenation sign "+" with your prefix string before vue variable into single quote. 
Ex.**

`:id=" 'prefix_string_'+ index "`

`:class=" 'prefix_string_'+ class "`

```
<div v-for="(tabTitle, index) in tabTitleList">
    <span :id="'sp_' + index"> {{tabTitle}} </span>
</div>
```

---

> **Same way for suffix**

**Use concatenation sign "+" with your suffix string after vue variable into single quote. 
Ex.**

`:id=" index + '_suffix_string' "`

`:class=" class + '_suffix_string'"`

```
<div v-for="(tabTitle, index) in tabTitleList">
    <span :id="index +'_sp'"> {{tabTitle}} </span>
</div>
```