# How to select a single row of a table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to select any single row in the table, but instead, if i click in any of the rows, it selects as if I clicked in the entire table.

```
<tbody>
          <tr v-for="info in infos" :key="info.id" id="tr-infos" @click="onRowSelect">
            <td width="310" height="30" class="td-info">
              <span class="info-span">{{info.noun}}</span>
            </td>
            <td width="310" height="30" class="td-info">
              <span class="info-span">{{info.department}}</span>
            </td>
            <td width="310" height="30" class="td-info">
              <span class="info-span">{{info.place}}</span>
            </td>
            <td width="310" height="30" class="td-info">
              <span class="info-span">{{info.role}}</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I also tried this. but returns undefined.

```
methods: {
    onRowSelect(x) {
      console.log(x.rowIndex);
    }
  }
```

I really dont know what to do in this point. Anyone can help?

Comment: `@click="onRowSelect(info)"`

Comment: note 1 : the resut of v-for is a list to <tr>, but each the id will be always "tr-infos" for each one.

Comment: note 2 : use @click="onRowSelec($event)"  and in methods : onRowSelect(evt)  { ... evt.currentTarget... }  (instead  evt.target )

Comment: for the 'id' issue : remove it , (may be it's useless , if you don't use it ?) else see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41312385/vue-js-how-to-set-id-prefix-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on a row, the `event.target` it is actually the innermost element that was clicked on. If you have a `<span>` element inside of each `<td>` that's in the row, the `<span>` element will likely be the `event.target` upon clicking that row. The `<span>` element's parent is the `<td>` element and the `.parentNode` of the `<td>` is the `<tr>` you're wanting.

So, one way to get the `<tr>`, is to climb the DOM hierarchy via `.parentNode` until the `element.tagName` is `TR`:

```js
function rowSelectHandler(event)
{
  let element = event.target;
  if(element.tagName === "TABLE")
  {
    console.log("You click on the table, without clicking a row.");
  }
  else
  {
    while(element.tagName !== "TR")
    {
     element = element.parentNode;
    }
    let row = element;
    console.log(row);
  }
}

let table = [... document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")][0];
table.addEventListener("click", rowSelectHandler);
```

```css
table
{
  background-color: blue;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
td
{
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
span
{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>In the table below, tr elements are blue, td elements are red, and span elements are yellow.</p>
<p>Click anywhere within the row to console.log its TR element:</p>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="info in infos" :key="info.id" id="tr-infos" @click="onRowSelect">
      <td width="310" height="30" class="td-info">
        <span class="info-span">{{info.noun}}</span>
      </td>
      <td width="310" height="30" class="td-info">
        <span class="info-span">{{info.department}}</span>
      </td>
      <td width="310" height="30" class="td-info">
        <span class="info-span">{{info.place}}</span>
      </td>
      <td width="310" height="30" class="td-info">
        <span class="info-span">{{info.role}}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I intentionally did not set table style to `border-collapse: collapse;`, so you can see how "clicking on the border between `<td>` elements" will not result in a row-click. Therefore, in your CSS, use `border-collapse: collapse;` on your table elements to avoid the possibility of clicking the table that's behind the row when the click happens between two cells.